# Gatsby.js - Typography themes

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I'm creating an application based on gatsby framework, but I have problem with initialize gatsby theme. From official documentation:

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-three/

```
import Typography from 'typography';
import fairyGateTheme from 'typography-theme-github';

const typography = new Typography(fairyGateTheme);

export const { scale, rhythm, options } = typography;
export default typography;
```

But typography-theme-github import has dotted underline when I hovered mouse on it I have got this tip:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'typography-theme-github'. '/Users/jozefrzadkosz/Desktop/hello-world/node_modules/typography-theme-github/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/typography-theme-github` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'typography-theme-github';`ts(7016)

When I run `gatsby develop` I'm getting this error:

> Error: Unable to find plugin "undefined". Perhaps you nee  d to install its package?

**EDIT**

I have looked on this file `node_modules/typography-theme-github/dist/index.js` and I found one similar issue:

```
var _grayPercentage = require("gray-percentage");
```

This require has exactly same tip as my theme import.

**SECOND EDIT**

Gatsby.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [`gatsby-plugin-sass`],
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography`
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: did you try to npm i -d typography to install the typography theme and save it as a dependancy?

Comment: Yeah I did and nothing

Comment: Nothing as in you don't have node package manager installed, or it throws an error? The tutorial advises you run "npm install --save gatsby-plugin-typography react-typography typography typography-theme-fairy-gates
"
Did that throw any error?

Comment: Nope, It just have been installed in dependencies and it have correctly installed in package.json, I have tried to reinstall all by 'npm i' and nothing worked. I was thinking maybe this theme is broken, so I have installed github theme and same result

Comment: The tip you get has nothing to do with the error message that you get. It's very likely that you forgot to specify plugin name in your gatsby-config, could you share your gatsby-config.js?

Comment: Edited for you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you placed `gatsby-plugin-sass` in an array, which is why `gatsby` didn't recognize it:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
-   [`gatsby-plugin-sass`], <-- error
+   `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography`
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

This is probably not a problem with `gatsby-plugin-typography`.

Comment: Wow, you are awesome, I didn't think that plugins must be a simple array :) Many many thanks!